# In an MS Build project file, can a Nuget package reference be given a path?

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild, nuget

I have a Nuget package that is downloaded to a non-standard location in my project folder.

Is it possible to reference this package in an `fsproj` or `csproj` file?

Something like:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0">
    <HintPath>./external/packages/Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff.3.6.0/</HintPath>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Why do you want a package in a non-standard location? This sounds like it might be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: @zivkan, sometimes packages are distributed on flash drive, it's common for closed source software

Answer (score 2):

Nuget can have multiple sources for packages, that can be configured with a [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) file. Source can be either URL of some site, like nuget.org or private feed from gitlab, or it can be path to local directory, like `C:/Packages/`.

You should create `nuget.config` file in a root of repository with following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- Make sure everyone have same sources for more reliability -->
    <clear /> 
    
    <!-- Add default nuget source, since we removed it -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    
    <!-- Add new source that will point to directory with *.nupkg files. 
         Parameter 'key' can have arbitrary text -->
    <add key="localFiles" value="./external/packages/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```